# django-rest ignore certain fields for certain objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue with rest-framework I'm not even sure if this is the right way to go about it or not. I have the following model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=POST_OPTIONS, default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", blank=True, null=True)
    s3Url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

And the following serializer for rest-framework

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.Field(source='get_imgage_url')
    image_file = serializers.ImageField()
    role = serializers.Field(source='get_role')

    class Meta:
        model = Post

        fields = ('url', 'user', 'created', 'updated', 'date', 'show', 'title', 'body', 'role', 'image_url', 'image')
        read_only_fields = ('user', 'created', 'updated')
```

So there are 2 kinds of posts.. a image and a text post. I dont want to show image or image_url if there is no image in the post.

I can't figure out how to make rest-framework do that.

thanks for the help!

Comment: One option is to write two different serializers. In your view you can then override the get_serializer_class() method to choose based on whether or not there is an image.

Comment: thanks.. I didn't know about that function so I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah the get_serializer_class() method is really easy to override. Here's how I used it for a special serializer if it was a get request. Just throw it in your model view.

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == "GET":
       return ProductGetSerializer
    return ProductSerializer
```

Comment: I don't think that's the right solution. It doesn't differentiate based on objects, just http method. Specifically, this won't work for list requests.